# WKWebiew not loading html string with parameters

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to load html string with swift parameters but it is not loading

```
let htmlStr = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src= "'\(jsUrl)'" id="xxxxx"
        data-error="ErrorCallback" data-cancel="CancelCallback" data-complete="CompleteCallback"
        data-timeout="TimeoutCallback">

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div style="clear: both;height: 3px;">
    </div>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    CheckoutConfigure();
    Checkout.showLightbox();
    function CancelCallback() {
        AndroidFunction.cancelCallback()
    }

    function ErrorCallback(response) {
        AndroidFunction.errorCallback(JSON.stringify(response))
    }

    function CompleteCallback(response,sessionVersion) {
        AndroidFunction.completeCallback(response, sessionVersion)
    }

    function TimeoutCallback() {
        AndroidFunction.timeoutCallback()
    }

    
</script>

</html>
"""
```

Here is calling function

```
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlStr, baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: What does "it is not loading" mean?

Comment: I see blank webview.@matt

Comment: Why would it be non-blank?

Comment: @matt same code in android is loading in webview

Comment: This HTML file results in a blank webpage even in Safari & Chrome.

Comment: Really? The _same_ code? I doubt that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making invalid HTML and JavaScript with your phrases like `id: "'\(orderId)'"`. Suppose `orderId` is 7. Now we have

```
id: "'7'"
```

Really? With two sets of quote delimiters? That's not valid JavaScript.

Comment: You know javascript? If you wrote a book I would buy it

Answer (score 0):

Need to connect each paragraph with "\n" in your script. Like this :
"" + "\n"
""